# Ubuntu doesn't recognice any command

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

First of all, i was installing CUDA with cuDNN, the thing is that i put some new paths on the `~/.bashrc` after that all the commands like `ls`, `sudo`, etc. doesn't work, it shows this message

`The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
sudo: command not found`

Do anyone knows what is the issue?

Comment: there are already such questions on askUbuntu. Why don't you see their answers?

Comment: I tried, but the answers didn't help me a lot

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the `/usr/bin` path in your `PATH` environment variable because this is where the `ls`, `cd` & all others built-in commands are located.

The easiest way is to update your `PATH` environment variable with the `export` method :

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/bin"
```

If the `export` method doesn't work for you, you can edit your `.bashrc` file (`nano ~/.bashrc`) and update the `PATH` variable by adding the `/usr/bin` path in it.

Good luck

Comment: The other problem is that `nano` doesn't work too it says `command not found`